Haystack PipelineConnectError: Cannot connect 'replies_to_query.output' with 'bm25_retriever.query'
I am new to the haystack framework and their pipelines. I am very convinced about the logic of the structure of the pipes but the error messages are still quite cryptic to me. I am trying to run a pretty standard rag-pipe from a rag-pipe template from deepset cloud. The only thing I had to change was the document_store because it was configured to OpenSearchDocumentStore and I want to run it locally (just to experiment). The error which is thrown says: PipelineConnectError: Cannot connect 'replies_to_query.output' with 'bm25_retriever.query': their declared input and output types do not match. Here is my code:
from haystack import Pipeline
from haystack.components.builders.prompt_builder import PromptBuilder
from haystack.utils import Secret
from haystack.components.generators.openai import OpenAIGenerator
from haystack.components.converters.output_adapter import OutputAdapter
from haystack.components.retrievers.in_memory import InMemoryBM25Retriever
from haystack.components.embedders.sentence_transformers_text_embedder import (
    SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder,
)
from haystack.components.retrievers import InMemoryEmbeddingRetriever
from haystack.components.joiners.document_joiner import DocumentJoiner
from haystack.components.rankers.transformers_similarity import (
    TransformersSimilarityRanker,
)
from haystack.components.builders import AnswerBuilder


chat_summary_prompt_builder = PromptBuilder(
    template="You are part of a chatbot.\nYou receive a question (Current Question) and a chat history.\nUse the context from the chat history and reformulate the question so that it is suitable for retrieval augmented generation.\nIf X is followed by Y, only ask for Y and do not repeat X again.\nIf the question does not require any context from the chat history, output it unedited.\nDon't make questions too long, but short and precise.\nStay as close as possible to the current question.\nOnly output the new question, nothing else!\n\n{{ question }}\n\nNew question:"
)
chat_summary_llm = OpenAIGenerator(
    api_key=Secret.from_env_var(["OPENAI_API_KEY"]),
    model="gpt-4o",
    generation_kwargs={"max_tokens": 650, "temperature": 0, "seed": 0},
)
replies_to_query = OutputAdapter(template="{{ replies[0] }}", output_type="str")
bm25_retriever = InMemoryBM25Retriever(top_k=20, document_store=document_store)
query_embedder = SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder(model="intfloat/e5-base-v2")
embedding_retriever = InMemoryEmbeddingRetriever(
    top_k=20, document_store=document_store
)
document_joiner = DocumentJoiner(join_mode="concatenate")
ranker = TransformersSimilarityRanker(
    model="intfloat/simlm-msmarco-reranker",
    top_k=8,
    model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": "auto"},
)
qa_prompt_builder = PromptBuilder(
    template="You are a technical expert.\nYou answer questions truthfully based on provided documents.\nIgnore typing errors in the question.\nFor each document check whether it is related to the question.\nOnly use documents that are related to the question to answer it.\nIgnore documents that are not related to the question.\nIf the answer exists in several documents, summarize them.\nOnly answer based on the documents provided. Don't make things up.\nJust output the structured, informative and precise answer and nothing else.\nIf the documents can't answer the question, say so.\nAlways use references in the form [NUMBER OF DOCUMENT] when using information from a document, e.g. [3] for Document[3].\nNever name the documents, only enter a number in square brackets as a reference.\nThe reference must only refer to the number that comes in square brackets after the document.\nOtherwise, do not use brackets in your answer and reference ONLY the number of the document without mentioning the word document.\nThese are the documents:\n{% for document in documents %}\nDocument[{{ loop.index }}]:\n{{ document.content }}\n{% endfor %}\n\nQuestion: {{ question }}\nAnswer:"
)
qa_llm = OpenAIGenerator(
    api_key=Secret.from_env_var(["OPENAI_API_KEY"]),
    model="gpt-4o",
    generation_kwargs={"max_tokens": 650, "temperature": 0, "seed": 0},
)
# answer_builder = DeepsetAnswerBuilder(reference_pattern="acm")
answer_builder = AnswerBuilder()

query_pipe = Pipeline()
query_pipe.add_component("chat_summary_prompt_builder", chat_summary_prompt_builder)
query_pipe.add_component("chat_summary_llm", chat_summary_llm)
query_pipe.add_component("replies_to_query", replies_to_query)
query_pipe.add_component("bm25_retriever", bm25_retriever)
query_pipe.add_component("query_embedder", query_embedder)
query_pipe.add_component("embedding_retriever", embedding_retriever)
query_pipe.add_component("document_joiner", document_joiner)
query_pipe.add_component("ranker", ranker)
query_pipe.add_component("qa_prompt_builder", qa_prompt_builder)
query_pipe.add_component("qa_llm", qa_llm)
query_pipe.add_component("answer_builder", answer_builder)
query_pipe.connect("chat_summary_prompt_builder.prompt", "chat_summary_llm.prompt")
query_pipe.connect("chat_summary_llm.replies", "replies_to_query.replies")
query_pipe.connect("replies_to_query.output", "bm25_retriever.query")
query_pipe.connect("replies_to_query.output", "query_embedder.text")
query_pipe.connect("replies_to_query.output", "ranker.query")
query_pipe.connect("replies_to_query.output", "qa_prompt_builder.question")
query_pipe.connect("replies_to_query.output", "answer_builder.query")
query_pipe.connect("bm25_retriever.documents", "document_joiner.documents")
query_pipe.connect("query_embedder.embedding", "embedding_retriever.query_embedding")
query_pipe.connect("embedding_retriever.documents", "document_joiner.documents")
query_pipe.connect("document_joiner.documents", "ranker.documents")
query_pipe.connect("ranker.documents", "qa_prompt_builder.documents")
query_pipe.connect("ranker.documents", "answer_builder.documents")
query_pipe.connect("qa_prompt_builder.prompt", "qa_llm.prompt")
query_pipe.connect("qa_prompt_builder.prompt", "answer_builder.prompt")
query_pipe.connect("qa_llm.replies", "answer_builder.replies")

{
    "name": "PipelineConnectError",
    "message": "Cannot connect 'replies_to_query.output' with 'bm25_retriever.query': their declared input and output types do not match.
'replies_to_query':
 - output: 'str'
'bm25_retriever':
 - query: str (available)",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PipelineConnectError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 63
     61 query_pipe.connect(\"chat_summary_prompt_builder.prompt\", \"chat_summary_llm.prompt\")
     62 query_pipe.connect(\"chat_summary_llm.replies\", \"replies_to_query.replies\")
---> 63 query_pipe.connect(\"replies_to_query.output\", \"bm25_retriever.query\")
     64 query_pipe.connect(\"replies_to_query.output\", \"query_embedder.text\")
     65 query_pipe.connect(\"replies_to_query.output\", \"ranker.query\")

File c:\\Local-Gits\\rag-comparison\\env\\Lib\\site-packages\\haystack\\core\\pipeline\\base.py:465, in PipelineBase.connect(self, sender, receiver)
    460     else:
    461         msg = (
    462             f\"Cannot connect '{sender_component_name}' with '{receiver_component_name}': \"
    463             f\"no matching connections available.\
{status}\"
    464         )
--> 465     raise PipelineConnectError(msg)
    467 if len(possible_connections) == 1:
    468     # There's only one possible connection, use it
    469     sender_socket = possible_connections[0][0]

PipelineConnectError: Cannot connect 'replies_to_query.output' with 'bm25_retriever.query': their declared input and output types do not match.
'replies_to_query':
 - output: 'str'
'bm25_retriever':
 - query: str (available)"
}

I hope it is reproducable and hope for suggestions or solutions!

Hello! I am from the Haystack team.
This works: replies_to_query = OutputAdapter(template="{{ replies[0] }}", output_type=str). You should specify the type (str) instead of "str".
Then your pipeline later breaks with a different error.
Next time, feel free to reach out on GitHub discussions/Discord if you want.

Alright, that worked! Thanks a lot. I copied this code from deepset cloud > export code > query > python. So maybe there is a bug in this code line and it should say type(str) instead of "str" as you pointed out?

We'll investigate. Thanks!

Hey @yaennu.s, thanks for bringing this up! We actually just shipped a fix for this :-)
